# LINQ performance vs. Dictionary<K,V>

Tags: c#, performance, linq, data-structures

In many situations, for simplicity's sake, I would have preferred to use a List or an HashSet in combination with LINQ instead of using a Dictionary. However, I usually sticked with Dictionary because I thought Dictionary would be more performant because of its hash table implementation.

For example:

When I do this in LINQ:

```
bool exists = hashset.Any(item => item.Key == someKey);
```

Do I lose significant performance compared to the following equivalent with a Dictionary?

```
bool exists = dictionary.ContainsKey(someKey); // an O(1) operation
```

Are the LINQ queries optimized in some way that would make them a justifiable choice against a Dictionary? Or is the above Any() a plain O(n) operation no matter on which type of collection it is executed?

Comment: You're passing it a delegate to execute on each item (until it returns true in this case), so yes, a dictionary look up is a lot faster (except for some very edge cases)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case you are eliminating the benefit of the hashset, because [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) in that case is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) defined on IEnumerable.  It is simply iterating over the hashset as if it were a List and invoking the == operator on each item.  In fact, these two code samples are not even strictly equivalent- the LINQ statement uses the == operator, and the dictionary uses hashcode/equals equality.  These are equivalent for value types and Strings, but not for all classes.

What you can do is this:

```
bool exists = hashset.Contains(item.Key);
```

That will use the Hashset's optimized lookup, and not require you to keep a dummy value as you would with Dictionary.

Comment: But when I encounter this problem, I usually want to store a collection of Item, not a collection of Item.Key. And if I store a collection of Item in a HashSet, I won't be able to search them by Key unless I use LINQ. Which is slow. And then I fall back to the Dictionary which seems to be the only way to go.

Comment: If Key is embedded in the value (as a field or property for instance), you want to subclass KeyedCollection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx. If the keys are not embedded in the values, then Dictionary is the right data structure.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks! Very clear explanation.

Comment: Equals and == are not equivalent for value types.  Did you mean to say "built-in value types"?